# Public connection to AWS Linux server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, server, virtual-machine

I'm quite new to setting up the config for servers.

I want to have a user connect my Linux server, I'm using AWS to host the virtual machine. I cannot find anywhere to do this without using the public key. I want the user to just have to enter a username and password.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: All servers on Cloud service providers are typically only accessible via ssh keys in order to allow enhanced security. Digital Ocean is an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Why the user will connect your server? Is for database operations or something? If it is for database operations, you can use an API for this. A direct user connection to server is not a good thing. If you want to connect your server for configurations, you can use ssh to connect to your server.

Comment: I'm setting up a Capture the flag for a project and want users to be able to connect to a server to complete the challenged